# axios not sending API requests (neither pre-flight nor normal)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, axios, fastapi

I am trying to call my own API at `http://127.0.0.1:8000`.
It works fine when I do it from a fresh react app `npx create-react-app: ...` with the same functions. It also works fine from other Apps (like the pycharm testing etc).
Within my app (that was build with the yeoman generator for office task pane add ins) I am able to call other APIs (that I don't host myself).
I looked into potential CORS issues but in my opinion I adjusted everything in the API and in the webpack that I saw in other questions that were answered here. CORS also can't really be, since the API server doesn't even register a pre-flight request by my app, so somehow just nothing gets out (it works however when I call other APIs).

The following function calls the API:

```
  getPlayground2 = async (name, prompt, engine, purpose, format, max_tokens, temperature, user) => {
    let configObject = {
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/completion",
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
      data: {
        name: name,
        prompt: prompt,
        engine: engine,
        purpose: purpose,
        format: format,
        max_tokens: max_tokens,
        temperature: temperature,
        user: user,
      },
    };
    // console feed for dev
    // grab available models
    console.log("playground2 called");
    axios
      .request(configObject)
      .then((res) => {
        //console.log(res);
        console.log(res.status);
        console.log(res.data);
        console.log("test");
        const completion = res.data.choices[0].text;
        return Promise.resolve(completion);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response);
        return Promise.reject();
      });
  };
```

The axios interceptor shows the following request:

```
{transitional: Object, adapter: ƒ xhrAdapter(), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 10000…}
▶transitional: Object
▶adapter: ƒ xhrAdapter() {}
▶transformRequest: Array(1)
▶transformResponse: Array(1)
 timeout: 10000
 xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN"
 xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN"
 maxContentLength: -1
 maxBodyLength: -1
▶env: Object
▶validateStatus: ƒ validateStatus() {}
▶headers: Object
 Accept: "application/json"
 Content-Type: "application/json"
 url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/completion"
 method: "post"
 data: "{"name":"button_playground_curie_prose_call","prompt":"I walk my dog to","engine":"curie","purpose":"playground","format":"prose","max_tokens":50,"temperature":0.7,"user":"devuser"}"
```

None of the `console.logs` in that function are being shown (in the other test apps they are though)(although that might be an issue with my console?)

The promise then resolves to `undefined`
When trying to `console.log` `res.data`

### Webpack Configurations

```
/* webpack.config.js*/
...
    devServer: {
      hot: true,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
      },
      https: env.WEBPACK_BUILD || options.https !== undefined ? options.https : await getHttpsOptions(),
      port: process.env.npm_package_config_dev_server_port || 3000,
    },
```

Further I tried to use `fetch` however that also throws an error that I can'T decrypt (unfortunately this is a task pane add in for microsoft, so I can't see the correct console logs).
With neither of the two methods is my API (Fast API) even registering an incoming request.

I am a bit lost, as to what might cause the problem and where to look further

Comment: None of the console.log statements get logged? Even not ```console.log("playground2 called");```?

Comment: My bad. That one is logged.. just nothing after.. so it seems to fail at the request part

Comment: And is there anything in the network tab of the console?